# Remove top admin bar

Tags: css, admin-bar

whenever admin or any other user logs in a top bar menu ads up. Now I made login for everybody, so I do not want this bar.

First I added `display:none` to `admin-bar.css`, but the main problem is that wordpress is still adding a white line on the top with:

```
html {
    margin-top: 28px !important;
}
```

How to remove this as this is causing some design flaws.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://vudu.me/88

Has an article about it.

But basically

```
/* Disable the Admin Bar. */
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

or also

```
//REMOVE ADMIN BAR
remove_action('init', 'wp_admin_bar_init');
```

I believe in your functions.php will disable it. Probably a better way than just hiding it thriough css

THe reason you still get the gap with the menu hidden is because WP adds this css as well

```
html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
* html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
```

So a margin is added up top.... you could negate that css in yours, but just disabling the bar is probably better if that's what you want to do

Answer (score 2):

To remove the top margin left by the admin bar, it's not enough just to set `show_admin_bar` to false. You also need to remove the admin bar bump callback:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb' );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the top bar that shows up with quicklinks for the admin, you can also disable it per user when you setup their profiles.

It's just a checkbox in the admin under the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Add this function in functions.php of your theme

```
function hide_admin_bar_from_front_end(){
  if (is_blog_admin()) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar_from_front_end' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to remove that white space (it's not caused by the admin bar) is to search out this CSS in `style.css`:

```
#page {
    margin: 2em auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

and switch the `2em` to `0em` or some variation of the same. That will remove the white space.

Answer (score 0):

### Disable the WordPress Admin Bar Using CSS

You only have to copy and paste the CSS code below in **Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS**, or your style.css file.

The CSS code to disable the toolbar is:

```
#wpadminbar { display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Only valid php solution:

1) For Front-End:

```
show_admin_bar(false);          //same as:  add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

2) For Back-End (tricky solution per [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin_bar_showing/)):

```
if ($from_dashboard_too)
{
    remove_action( 'in_admin_header', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 0 );
    //disables top margin
    add_filter( 'admin_title', function(){ $GLOBALS['wp_query']->is_embed=true;  add_action('admin_xml_ns', function(){ $GLOBALS['wp_query']->is_embed=false; } ); } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the `functions.php` and I was trying to solve the same issue just via frontend with the Enfold theme I was using. Like the previous answer from [@DavidTaubmann](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/366467/209290), I used the same CSS edit, but that will still leave a 28px blank space at the top of the page, so here is the solution that worked for me.

---

From `your-wordpress-site.com/wp-admin` dashboard, go down to

- **Appearance > Customize**
- Click **Additional CSS**.

Copy and paste this:

```
#wpadminbar { display:none !important;}
html { margin-top: 0px !important; }
html body { margin-top: 0px !important; }
```

- Click **Publish**!

---

For other helpful solutions you can refer to:

- [How to Disable the WordPress Admin Bar- va](https://cpothemes.com/disable-wordpress-admin-bar)
- [*How do I remove the admin bar (styling) from frontend only?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30309/how-do-i-remove-the-admin-bar-styling-from-frontend-only)

Answer (score -2):

To remove the top admin bar you need to go to *Users* in the left Menu, then *Edit* the user and then disable the *Show toolbar when viewing website* checkbox. Save. Done.
Do this to all users.