# How do I remove the admin bar (styling) from frontend only?

Tags: admin-bar

When logged in, the admin bar adds the following to my page `<head>` section:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
```

Now, I can remove this by disabling the admin bar

```
/* Disable the Admin Bar. */
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

or removing it completely

```
/* Remove admin bar */
remove_action('init', 'wp_admin_bar_init');
```

I would like to keep the admin bar in the admin interface and only remove the CSS from front end.

I already use CSS reset where I set `margin: 0px`, but the admin-bar styling overrides this.

So how can I remove the styling from front end?

PS. I know I can disable the admin bar per user, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove top admin bar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/remove-top-admin-bar)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
function hide_admin_bar_from_front_end(){
  if (is_blog_admin()) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar_from_front_end' );
```

Edit:

As @Walf suggested in the comments, this could be writen as:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'is_blog_admin');
```

Comment: Ah :) I was testing for admin when I tried something similar. Forgot about the `is_blog_admin`. Thanks :)

Comment: which file does this go in...I'm pretty new to WP...

Comment: @HiroProtagonist it can be defined in any plugin or in functions.php of your theme.

Comment: This doesn't remove the CSS `margin-top: 28px !important` from the front-end though?

Comment: Thanx mate...worked perfactly

Comment: You can shorten it a bit: ```add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', function (){
    return is_blog_admin()
});```

Comment: You can shorten it *a lot*: `add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'is_blog_admin');` I suggested the edit but it was rejected. I guess the two high-powered reviewers saw it as too much change without realising it is **exactly** the same.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me :)

Answer (score 6):

f you want to remove the admin bar (toolbar) AND the bump CSS from your page, use this:

```
function wpse_99333_hide_admin_bar_from_front_end(){
  if ( is_blog_admin() ) {
    return true;
  }
  remove_action( 'wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb' );
  return false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'wpse_99333_hide_admin_bar_from_front_end' );
```

The `_admin_bar_bump_cb` function is the one that inserts the CSS (located in wp-includes/admin-bar.php)

Answer (score 1):

**I would do something like this :**

**Remove admin bar / CSS in head / body class**

```
show_admin_bar(false);
```

or if you just want to : **Remove `html` margin-top CSS in `<head>`**

```
function remove_admin_bar_bump() {
   remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_bar_bump');
```

***Tested :*** Version 4.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this, I just wanted wordpress's default inline css styles (for the admin bar) removed, but I did want the admin bar to remain. I was displaying the admin bar at the bottom of the page, not the top.

Here is what got rid of injecting the styles from the _admin_bar_bump_cb function for me. I added the following to my functions.php

```js
// remove wordpress trying to style the admin bar with inline css
function hide_admin_bar_from_front_end(){
  remove_action( 'wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb' );
  return true;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar_from_front_end' );
```