# wp_head() gives me some weird CSS

Tags: css, wp-head

I was trying to enqueue my stylesheets but it didn't work. Turns out I had forgotten to include `wp_head()` inside my `<head>` tag. So I did and then my stylesheets where loading fine.

The problem is that a get a CSS value that is not from my stylesheet. And I can also not override it from my stylesheet since it appears to be loading after mine. It started to come up as soon as I included `wp_head()`. If I delete `wp_head()` everything looks fine.

This is the weird CSS value that I get:

```
media="screen" 
html {
    margin-top: 32px !important;
}
```

As you can understand this is a problem since I know have a 32px margin on top of my websites. And as I stated before, I have no idea where this value comes from. I use no plugins and the only stylesheet enqueued is my `style.css` and this value is not from that file. In the "console" it says that the value comes from "index" on line 334. But I got nothing there, so it must be something from WP?

Can anyone explain to me where this value comes from? And how do I change it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fact that

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
```

is added for Admin bar by wp-core at the top of the site.

The trick below will remove those CSS out from yout HTML output Just add this code to your `functions.php`

```
add_action('get_header', 'my_filter_head');

function my_filter_head() {
   remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
```

**UPDATE**

Answering question-starter request.

**1)** Admin Bar is showing by default if you're logged in. It wrapper has `id="wpadminbar"` in your HTML responce.

It also enqueue `/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js` script and add "Support Script" at the bottom of page.

**2)** Admin Bar can be disabled when you're viewing site for specified users at 
Users -> User_Record -> "Show Toolbar when viewing site" checkbox.

Additionally it can be disabled in your `functions.php` (using [`show_admin_bar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar) filter as described here [How do I remove the admin bar (styling) from frontend only?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30309/how-do-i-remove-the-admin-bar-styling-from-frontend-only))

**3)** In WP source code `_admin_bar_bump_cb()` looks like this. It can be found at [`wp-includes/admin-bar.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/admin-bar.php/)

```
function _admin_bar_bump_cb() { ?>
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
     html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
     * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
     @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
         html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
         * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
     }
 </style>
 <?php
}
```

This function is used to be added as action to `wp_head` inside [`wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php/) in this way:

```
if ( empty($header_callback) )
   $header_callback = '_admin_bar_bump_cb';

   add_action('wp_head', $header_callback);
```

By removing `_admin_bar_bump_cb` from action queue you cancel those styles printing

Comment: Ah, I see know that if I logged out this value dissapear. I am new to WP and still trying to learn. So I would be happy if you could explain this a bit more. If this code is to give space for the adminbar, why can't I see the adminbar? Am I supposed to see the adminbar on home.php when I am logedin? If not why does WP have a code that affects my home.php? The codes you posted, what does it do? And how does it affect the visibiltiy of the adminbar?

Comment: Updated answer considering your questions.

Comment: Consdering your isssue about "Why you cant see adminbar but still see 32px margins". I dont know the background of your template but i know it ususally happens when developers try to disable sidebar part-by-part in old-manner, forgetting about `show_admin_bar` filter