# Removing admin bar from wordpress dashboard

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard, admin-bar

I'm using wordpress multiste 3.3.1
I'm not gonna update it in the future. So I disabled all upgrade functions.

I want to remove the wordpress admin bar from both frontend as well as dashboard.

I can remove it from frontend using this code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'disable_admin_bar', 1 );
function disable_admin_bar() {
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
}
```

But i couldn't find any solution to remove it from dashboard.

**I don't want to use css solution to hide admin bar
and I'm ready to edit the core files to remove it**

Can anyone help me to remove it completely?. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend removing the admin bar from the admin section especially when running a multi-site setup. The admin bar is where the navigation is now put to navigate between all your sites and get to the network admin. If you remove it you will have to code in your own menu else where or remember all the URLs...

Comment: upgrading your wordpress is highly recommanded when new version arrives. It will keep your site secured.

Comment: @Brady I can access the network admin with this url `/wp-admin/network/` I can access all my sites from this link `/wp-admin/my-sites.php`

Comment: "I'm ready to edit the core" sounds like "I'm ready to die for my country". It does a good line in a movie script, I can even see Tom Cruise saying it! ;)

Comment: @brasofilo   ;)  .....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove top admin bar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/remove-top-admin-bar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!function_exists('disableAdminBar')) {

    function disableAdminBar(){

    remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );

    function remove_admin_bar_style_backend() {
      echo '<style>body.admin-bar #wpcontent, body.admin-bar #adminmenu { padding-top: 0px !important; }</style>';
    }

    add_filter('admin_head','remove_admin_bar_style_backend');

  }

}

add_filter('admin_head','remove_admin_bar_style_backend');
```

Source: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-disable-the-admin-bar-in-wordpress-3-3/

OR, for both front and back end...

```
if (!function_exists('disableAdminBar')) {

    function disableAdminBar(){

    remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 ); // for the admin page
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 ); // for the front end

    function remove_admin_bar_style_backend() {  // css override for the admin page
      echo '<style>body.admin-bar #wpcontent, body.admin-bar #adminmenu { padding-top: 0px !important; }</style>';
    }

    add_filter('admin_head','remove_admin_bar_style_backend');

    function remove_admin_bar_style_frontend() { // css override for the frontend
      echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen">
      html { margin-top: 0px !important; }
      * html body { margin-top: 0px !important; }
      </style>';
    }

    add_filter('wp_head','remove_admin_bar_style_frontend', 99);

  }

}

// add_filter('admin_head','remove_admin_bar_style_backend'); // Original version
add_action('init','disableAdminBar'); // New version
```

THat looks like it should do it.... May I go on record as saying that planning to never update WordPress is a terrible idea. If nothing else, for security reasons.

Some CSS is required in there, or else you end up with a big gap where the bar used to be. NOTE: I've not tested this, as I have no need. But that source is normally quite reliable.

Answer (score 5):

Use this small plugin, also available on Gist: https://gist.github.com/1503172
Works fine and is also a part of the plugin free "Adminimize".

```
add_action( 'init', 'fb_remove_admin_bar', 0 );
function fb_remove_admin_bar() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'admin-bar' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'admin-bar' );
    remove_action( 'init', '_wp_admin_bar_init' );
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
    remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
    // maybe also: 'wp_head'
    foreach ( array( 'wp_head', 'admin_head' ) as $hook ) {
        add_action(
            $hook,
            create_function(
                    '',
                    "echo '<style>body.admin-bar, body.admin-bar #wpcontent, body.admin-bar #adminmenu {
                         padding-top: 0px !important;
                    }
                    html.wp-toolbar {
                        padding-top: 0px !important;
                    }</style>';"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the action:

```
remove_action('init', 'wp_admin_bar_init');
```

Comment: I think the function is `_wp_admin_bar_init`, with `_`.

Comment: @bueltge admin-bar.php:39 `add_action( 'init', '_wp_admin_bar_init' ); // Don't remove. Wrong way to disable.` :) `wp_admin_bar_init` is viable.

Comment: But I cant find the function `wp_admin_bar_init`. Have you more hints for to understand this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update for WordPress 5.*

..and WORKS FINE!!

There are two new lines for **remove_admin_bar_style_backend()** function and a new function to remove backend footer

```
/* 
* Removes WordPress framework dashboard horizontal banners (adminbar & footer)
*/
if (!function_exists('disable_framework_banners'))
{
    function disable_framework_banners()
    {
        function remove_admin_bar_style_frontend() 
        {
            // CSS override for the frontend
            echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen">html { margin-top: 0px !important; } * html body { margin-top: 0px !important; } </style>';
        }
        add_filter('wp_head','remove_admin_bar_style_frontend', 99);
        
        function remove_wpadminbar_backend()
        {
            // CSS override for the admin page
            echo '<style>html.wp-toolbar { padding-top:0!important; }</style>';
            echo '<style>#wpadminbar { display:none!important }</style>';
        }
        add_filter('admin_head','remove_wpadminbar_backend');

        function remove_wpfooter_backend()
        {
            // CSS override for the admin page
            echo '<style>#wpfooter { display:none!important }</style>';
        }
        add_filter('admin_head','remove_wpfooter_backend');
    }
}
add_action('init','disable_framework_banners');
```