# Disable the admin bar

Tags: admin-bar

I have the WP3.4 and I would like to disable the admin bar. I have tried to do that with many ways, but the admin bar do not display. Is possible to do on this version of WP (3.4) or i make a mistake in the code?
Below are the ways that I've tried.
Thanks in advance.
The 1st :

```
function my_function_admin_bar(){
            return false;
        }
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

The 2nd :

```
add_action( 'init', 'disable_admin_bar', 1 );
function disable_admin_bar() {
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

The 3rd

```
    <?php
if (!function_exists('disableAdminBar')) {

    function disableAdminBar(){

    remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 ); // for the admin page
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 ); // for the front end

    function remove_admin_bar_style_backend() {  // css override for the admin page
      echo '<style>body.admin-bar #wpcontent, body.admin-bar #adminmenu { padding-top: 0px !important; }</style>';
    }

    add_filter('admin_head','remove_admin_bar_style_backend');

    function remove_admin_bar_style_frontend() { // css override for the frontend
      echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen">
      html { margin-top: 0px !important; }
      * html body { margin-top: 0px !important; }
      </style>';
    }

    add_filter('wp_head','remove_admin_bar_style_frontend', 99);

  }

}

// add_filter('admin_head','remove_admin_bar_style_backend'); // Original version
add_action('init','disableAdminBar'); // New version


    ?>
```

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to "disable" it in the backend, only in the frontend. Your tests do disable it in the frontend, right?

Comment: The tests do not disable the admin bar backend or frontend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove top admin bar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/remove-top-admin-bar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the order or number which signifies when the Hook gets fired. In this case I beleive it's `0` and the filter is: `wp_admin_bar_render`. The action to remove the function I believe is:

```
remove_action( 'in_admin_header', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 0);
```

The Function Reference:

[Function Reference/remove action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

And here it is in the core file:

[WordPress Trac.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L67)

Comment: Thanks for the help, works, but there’s still a padding at the top of the page. I think that i want to customize with little css code.

Comment: @MikeD, exactly, just tested and added to an `admin_head` action: `#wpwrap {position: absolute;top: 0px;}`

Answer (score 4):

The simple front-end removal is via [`show_admin_bar()`](http://queryposts.com/function/show_admin_bar/):

```
show_admin_bar( false );
```

This won't affect admin, because it is considered non-removable there (was not when first introduced, but later changed to that approach). [`is_admin_bar_showing()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_admin_bar_showing/) is hardcoded to always return true on admin side and there is no "proper" way to remove toolbar there. Which is not to say it *can't* be done, but that is probably *shouldn't* be done.

Answer (score 2):

That's a fast and right solution, but does not deactivate all requirements. For example, the scripts and styles are still active and have its load time. A complete solution in a small plugin as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Remove Admin Bar in WordPress 3.3
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40983/removing-admin-bar-from-wordpress-dashboard
 * Description: Remove Admin Bar
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author:      Frank Bültge
 * Author URI:  http://bueltge.de
 * License:     GPLv3
 */

// This file is not called from WordPress. We don't like that.
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) and exit;

add_action( 'init', 'fb_remove_admin_bar', 0 );
function fb_remove_admin_bar() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'admin-bar' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'admin-bar' );
    remove_action( 'init', '_wp_admin_bar_init' );
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
    remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
    // maybe also: 'wp_head'
    foreach ( array( 'admin_head' ) as $hook ) {
        add_action(
            $hook,
            create_function(
                '',
                "echo '<style>body.admin-bar #wpcontent, body.admin-bar
#adminmenu { padding-top: 0px !important; }</style>';"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

also as [gist](https://gist.github.com/bueltge/1503172) for download and forks.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to put it in 'code' to be visible for everyone. Thanks.

Comment: Frank, I interpreted your original sentences, hopefully I got it right ;) :::: Great script +1

Comment: Thanks for edit my answer, is not possible to write good code with a tablet. I miss tags for code, markdown is not useable with tablets.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution.
functions.php :

```
require_once('includes/admin/remove_admin_bar.php');
```

and the php file :

```
    <?php
        remove_action( 'in_admin_header', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 0);
        echo '<style>body.admin-bar #wpwrap
{padding-top: 0px !important; position:absolute; top: 0px;} </style>';  
    ?>
```

Comment: This may work but it's completely wrong... Your echo is printed **as the very first thing** in the page. Bueltge answer is the best one, IMO.

Comment: What do you mean with: **as the very first thing**? i want to disable the admin bar for backend. And for frontend i use : `show_admin_bar(false);`

Comment: If you do `echo '<whatever>';` straight in your *functions.php*, all your site will printing: `<whatever><html><head></head><body></body></html>`... I'm not sure Google will like it...

Comment: I am sorry about that and for this side you have right. Also, after many tests with the `echo` i realized that the head (`html`) of my site move slowly down.

Comment: i found many solutions, but first i want to be sure that one of these is the correct solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**if the current user is not an admin** or do not have administrative access

`yourCHILDtheme/functions.php`

```php
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
  add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

Tested: WordPress 5+