# Hide the wp-admin bar from dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I want to hide the admin bar from dashboard. I tried with following code:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
 
function remove_admin_bar() {

 if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
   show_admin_bar(false);
  }
}
```

It hide the admin bar when a logged in admin visit as front-end user. I actually want to hide the admin bar from dashboard back-end as indicated by red arrow in the following picture:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove top admin bar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/remove-top-admin-bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be not proper approach but this worked for me while testing. 
You can use these combinations to remove all links from Toolbar (admin-bar ) and then hide empty tool bar with css:

```
function remove_admin_bar_links() {
  global $wp_admin_bar;
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');          // Remove the WordPress logo
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('about');            // Remove the about WordPress link
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wporg');            // Remove the WordPress.org link
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('documentation');    // Remove the WordPress documentation link
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('support-forums');   // Remove the support forums link
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('feedback');         // Remove the feedback link
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('site-name');        // Remove the site name menu
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('view-site');        // Remove the view site link
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('updates');          // Remove the updates link
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');         // Remove the comments link
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-content');      // Remove the content link
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('w3tc');             // If you use w3 total cache remove the performance link
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('my-account');       // Remove the user details tab
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );


function hide_admin_bar() { ?>
  <style type="text/css">

    #wpadminbar {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
<?php }
// on backend area
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_admin_bar' );
// on frontend area
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_admin_bar' );
```

For more details read this [link](https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-remove-links-from-wordpress-admin-bar)

Out put is like below screenshot:

[image]